# ICMP / PING "Server" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, ping, icmp

Is it possible to write an ICMP Server in Ruby? If we install this server let's say on 192.168.1.4 and a m/c on 192.168.1.6 pings 192.168.1.4 then the Custom Ruby ICMP server would send the response and not the built in ICMP Server.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is three questions:

1. *"How do I prevent the host from replying to pings?"* -- you'll have to ask [Severfault](http://www.serverfault.com/) with details about your system.
2. *"How do I tell when I've been pinged?"* -- There are host-specific ways to do this, but [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) is fairly portable and may be easier. It turns out there exist [Ruby bindings](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/rubypcap/).
3. *"How do I generate ICMP responses?"* -- You want a library that generates packets. There are [lots of libs and tools](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/links.htm) that can do this, and it turns out there exist [ones for Ruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/packgen/).

You'll probably need to know [the message formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping#Message_format) of the ICMP request (ping) and ICMP response (pong) packets.